# How do I read a CSV file into a nested dictionary without import of modules

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that I want to read into a dictionary of dictionaries so that I can index into the dictionary with for example `['Aruba']['2020.05.22']['New_cas']` to access the new cases for Aruba on a certain date. For my own learning, how can it be done without imports, as there are plenty of examples of that on the web?

This ís a snippet of the CSV:

```
iso,Con,Loc,Dat,Cas,New_cas
aaa,bbb,helsinki,2020.05.18,5,4
aaa,bbb,Aruba,2020.05.22,4,8
aaa,bbb,copenhagen,2020.07.19,8,
aaa,bbb,oslo,2020.02.03,10,19
aaa,bbb,oslo,2019.02.18,21,2
aaa,bbb,oslo,2019.02.18,,13
```

My code so far:

```
dict= {} 
with open('filename.csv') as file:
    file.readline()  
    for line in file:
        iso,Con,Loc,Dat,Cas,New_cas = (s.strip('"') for s in line.split(','))
        if New_cas :
            if Loc not in dict:
                 dict[location] = [(New_cas ,Dat)]
            else:
                dict[location].append((New_cas ,Dat))
```

Form of the output of the current code

```
{'Aruba': [('2020-03-13', '2.0'), ('2020.05.22', '2.0'), ('2020-03-24', '8.0')..etc]}
```

Expected output:

```
print(covid_dict_3['helsinki']['2020.05.18']['New_cas'])
# 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This Out

```
my_dict= {}
with open('filename.csv') as file:
    file.readline()
    for line in file:
        iso,Con,Loc,Dat,Cas,New_cas = (s.strip('"') for s in line.split(','))
        New_cas = New_cas.strip("\n")
        New_cas = int(New_cas) if New_cas != '' else 0
        if Cas :
            if Loc not in my_dict:
                my_dict[Loc] = {Dat : { "New_cas" : New_cas }}
            else:
                if Dat not in my_dict[Loc]:
                    my_dict[Loc][Dat] = { "New_cas" : New_cas }
                else:
                    my_dict[Loc][Dat]["New_cas"] += New_cas

print(my_dict['helsinki']['2020.05.18']['New_cas'])

#prints : 4

# when you need to get any city/date, you first check a city exists or not in you data otherwise you would get keyError

if 'delhi' not in my_dict:
    print('No Case found against the city provided')
    exit()

if '2020.09.01' not in my_dict['helsinki']:
    print('No Case found against the date provided in helsinki')
    exit()

print(my_dict['helsinki']['2020.05.18']['New_cas'])
```

Comment: but this is for New_cas mostly, is there a way to rather than just reading in the new_cas field,  to read in all the columns

Comment: Append whatever you need in this line  { "New_cas" : New_cas } , e.g. add iso then  { "New_cas" : New_cas, "iso" : iso }

Comment: Hm i get a KeyError: 'copenhagen' when i run print(my_dict['copenhagen']['2020-10-10']['New_cas']) And the dictionary is empty

Comment: copenhagen city has new cases on 2020.07.19 not 2020-10-10

Comment: Yea but it is a larger sheet i have, where data is valid, but the dictionary is empty, we do not append anymore? copenhagen, 020.07.19,8, don't work either :/ as the dictionary is not filled with anything. i think it is when i try to do it for all columns

Comment: can you update your input so that i get the same error

Comment: If a country or date is not in your data, it would give you keyError, So you should always first check for the key first when getting. Use if key in my_dict  for Location , if key in my_dict[Loc] for any case against date

Comment: i am not sure i understand anymore, would you be okay with updating the answer?

Comment: only thing i dont understand now is the "if Cas :" why are we looking for that one

Comment: i just copied that from your code, you can remove it , there is no use of it, I kept it because  of the original code

Comment: I could not get it to work, it did not append to dictionary, so i was empty no matter what i tried. :(  therefor it could not find the cities and dates. if you can fix it will keep your answer, as it fulfills more by not using imports, map or zip :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223705/discussion-between-aft2233-and-rahul-juneja-devops).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `csv` module to parse the file:

```
import csv

data = {}
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as f_in:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
    for line in reader:
        loc = line.pop('Loc')
        dat = line.pop('Dat')
        data.setdefault(loc, {})[dat] = line

print(data['Aruba']['2020.05.22']['New_cas'])
```

Prints:

```
8
```

---

The `data` dictionary looks like this:

```
{'Aruba': {'2020.05.22': {'Cas': '4',
                          'Con': 'bbb',
                          'New_cas': '8',
                          'iso': 'aaa'}},
 'copenhagen': {'2020.07.19': {'Cas': '8',
                               'Con': 'bbb',
                               'New_cas': '',
                               'iso': 'aaa'}},
 'helsinki': {'2020.05.18': {'Cas': '5',
                             'Con': 'bbb',
                             'New_cas': '4',
                             'iso': 'aaa'}},
 'oslo': {'2019.02.18': {'Cas': '',
                         'Con': 'bbb',
                         'New_cas': '13',
                         'iso': 'aaa'},
          '2020.02.03': {'Cas': '10',
                         'Con': 'bbb',
                         'New_cas': '19',
                         'iso': 'aaa'}}}
```

---

EDIT: Version without headers:

```
data = {}
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as f_in:
    header = [*map(str.strip, next(f_in).split(','))]
    for line in f_in:
        line = dict(zip(header, map(str.strip, line.split(','))))
        loc = line.pop('Loc')
        dat = line.pop('Dat')
        data.setdefault(loc, {})[dat] = line

print(data['Aruba']['2020.05.22']['New_cas'])
```

Comment: I really want to understand and do it without imports